Ping the uplink device via NAT
I have two routers. One is connected to the Internet, has a WAN IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, internal IP 192.168.10.1, and DHCP server 192.168.10.*
The second router connects to the first one via WAN and gets a DHCP IP 192.168.10.213 with Gateway 192.168.10.1 (the first router). It also has NAT with its internal IP 192.168.8.1 and DHCP 192.168.8.*
If I connect via ethernet to router 1, I can connect to 192.168.10.1, but if I connect to the router 2 and try to connect to the router 1 (192.168.10.1), I get the following error:
92 bytes from console.gl-inet.com (192.168.8.1): Destination Port Unreachable
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 5400 2d5f   0 0000  3f  01 ba4a 192.168.8.174  192.168.10.1

What do I need to do on the first or second router to make the first router reachable for NAT clients of the second router?
Both routers have OpenWRT.

To me, that error looks like Router 2 is telling you it can't forward your ICMP echo request to Router 1. Diagnosing this may require inspecting Router 2's route table, ARP table, firewall rules, and NAT rules. And maybe the subnet masks in use on its LAN and WAN interfaces. Does Router 2 have firewall rules blocking egress of packets addressed to private addresses?
